# Convert a large SQL Server table to XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing, for-xml

I have a large table in SQL Server 2008 with roughly 500000 records and 40 columns. Some columns are string and they contain `\n` and other symbols. I want to convert this table to an XML file for use in project. When I use `FOR XML` to export this table, some errors are shown.

For example, when test:

```
select testData.* 
from testData 
FOR XML PATH('sample'), Type, ELEMENTS, ROOT(TestData')
```

only 3500 records are converted to XML and also, final element (that is record 3500) is not complete.

When test (without `Type`):

```
select testData.* 
from testData 
FOR XML PATH('sample'), ELEMENTS, ROOT(TestData')
```

All the records are converted to XML but some `CR/LF` character are added to the XML file that failed xml file. So, some tag like Product split to `prod CRLF uct`.

I searched for a long time but no page was helpful.

Comment: Are you directing the output to a file?  In SSMS there is a limit to what is displayed.

Comment: Yes. I tested that. but nothing change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a one-shot work, you can use the soft Altova XMLSpy, which is free during 30 days. The Altova mission kit suite contains a lot of tools like XML MapForce which can map a db to a xml.

Comment: Thanks. IS it ok for large table?

Comment: There  are no restriction regarding the size of the tables on the evaluation version. I've used it to convert a large XML file to a SQL relational database without problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to use this software. I downloaded it, but it seems very complex :(

Comment: Thanks  iguypouf. Your suggestion was very helpful. I converted that.